# APNS and GCM for Android, iOs and Browsers

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Dear stackoverflow guys,

I want to use APNS and GCM  to create push notifications like a boss. But one thing is still unclear to me. I wonder if the process of registration of the client(for whom we send push-messages from server) is same for Android and Chrome?(Safari and iOS)

What is different except device_id when I send push message from the server to browser and to android app?

Can I expect that when I send a message via GCM(or APNS) it will be delivered for Browsers and for Android devices as well?(if correct id specified)

Should I manually style them differently?

Or I should handle browser users and Android app users like absolutely different entities?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the messy message, xnagpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I wonder if the process of registration of the client(for whom we send push-messages from server) is same for Android and Chrome?(Safari and iOS)**

*From the [GCM Android docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)* :

> An Android application needs to register with GCM connection servers
>   before it can receive messages. When an app registers, it receives a
>   registration token and sends it to the app server. The client app
>   should store a boolean value indicating whether the registration token
>   has been sent to the server. Google provides the Instance ID API to
>   handle the creation and updating of registration tokens.

*From the [GCM Chrome docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)*:

> For Chrome apps and extensions, GCM enables Chrome instances to send
>   and receive message data from servers. The chrome.gcm API allows the
>   Chrome apps or extensions to access the GCM service. The service works
>   even if an app or extension isn't currently running.

*From the [GCM iOS docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)*:

> Before it can receive messages, an iOS application needs to register
>   with both Apple Push Notification service (APNs) and the GCM
>   connection server. When a client app registers with GCM, it receives a
>   registration token, which it must then send to the app server (the
>   APNs device token is not sent to the server). The client app must
>   store a boolean value indicating whether the registration token has
>   been sent to the server.

**What is different, except device_id, when I send push message from the server to browser and to android app?**

Chrome apps and extensions can access the GCM service directly through chrome.gcm API. Android needs to setup configurations like Google Play Services, manifests, etc.

**Can I expect that when I send a message via GCM(or APNS) it will be delivered for Browsers and for Android devices as well?(if correct id specified)**
      Yes.

**I should handle browser users and Android app users like absolutely different entities?** 
GCM was built to support chrome, ios, and android. Watch this [Google GCM video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owhf42SZadk) for additional info.